ZTE Blade A54 reboots and resets its Phone, Contacts and Messages applications to the Google's ones
ZTE Blade A54 phone comes out of the box with Google applications for Phone, Contacts and Messages.
Yesterday I downloaded alternative applications from Fossify and set them as default ones.
Now I heared the phone vibrating. It seems that it rebooted without any obvious reason. After it booted, I found out that Phone, Contacts and Messages applications were resetted back to the Google's ones.
I thought that it was an automatic system update, but according to the log, the last system update was installed a month ago.
How to find out which application / service triggered the restoration? Was it Google Play? Was it some system guard service? Howwto find it out?

Don't forget that on recent Android version system updates are not alone. There are Google Play updates as well as Pony Express (apex) updates that can be installed. Not sure what can trigger a restore if default app settings. Had you disabled/deactivated the Google apps you mentikned?
